# Making HTTP Request Calls to an API / Providing Data in the Body of the Post

Tags: json, http, flutter

I'm trying to make an http request to an API that takes an image and detects if there's any nudity in the image.

API Source: https://rapidapi.com/macgyverapi/api/nudity-detection/endpoints

**Expected Response:**

"{ "true": "0.977926", "false": "0.0220745" }"

**My attempt below produces the error:**

I/flutter ( 9838): {error: The algorithm generated an error on that request}

Below is my code and a working HTTP version under that

**My Attempt:**

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main(List<String> arguments) async {
  var url = 'https://macgyverapi-nudity-detection-v1.p.rapidapi.com/';

  // Await the http get response, then decode the json-formatted response.
  var body = json.encode({'key': 'free',  'id': '8E5q5T2p',  'data': {'image': 'https://askmacgyver.com/images/nude.jpg'}});
  Map<String,String> headers = {'x-rapidapi-host': 'macgyverapi-nudity-detection-v1.p.rapidapi.com','x-rapidapi-key': '5fbb8f70e6msh04e1ddd09f7fbb9p109a04jsn386ca971275a',  'content-type': 'application/json',  'accept': 'application/json'};

  final response = await http.post(url, body: body, headers: headers);
  final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  print(responseJson);
}
```

**Working HTTP Version:**

```
var http = require("https");

var options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "hostname": "macgyverapi-nudity-detection-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
    "port": null,
    "path": "/",
    "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "macgyverapi-nudity-detection-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "5fbb8f70e6msh04e1ddd09f7fbb9p109a04jsn386ca971275a",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "accept": "application/json"
    }
};

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
    var chunks = [];

    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    res.on("end", function () {
        var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        console.log(body.toString());
    });
});

req.write(JSON.stringify({
  key: 'free',
  id: '8E5q5T2p',
  data: {image: 'https://askmacgyver.com/images/nude.jpg'}
}));
req.end();
```

Comment: Even your JavaScript version is giving the same error. The image url you are trying is down, so that maybe the reason. Try with some other image.

Comment: I tried with another image and it works. So the problem is with the image url.

Comment: You're right thanks so much the API example code had an outdated URL that I was using